# How to save data to a file using outputstreams or in any efficient way?

Tags: ipad, nsdata, nsfilemanager, nsoutputstream

I have implemented in app purchase in my application,and the content i need to download from the store  would be large.All these days i have been using dictionary to store the received data from the connection:didReceiveData and finally store the store the dictionary data to a file which is fine for if the data to be downloaded is less.

I am facing memory issues when the product to be downloaded is heavy,since i am storing the whole data in a dictionary.When i searched for a mechanism i came across people suggesting to use outputStreams which enable us to save the pieces of received data to a file at runtime.

Can anyone help me with  a example implementation how to implement it.

Any other mechanism is also thankful.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

hi guys i have used **NSFileHandle** to download chunk by chunk data received into a file.
Apple documentation helped me to do this easily.

THank you